# How to 'forward' all-but-the-first-argument arguments of a function to another function?

Tags: javascript

How do I forward the arguments from within a function to another function?

I have this:

```
function SomeThing(options) {
  function callback(callback_name) {
    if(options[callback_name]) {
      // Desiring to call the callback with all arguments that this function
      // received, except for the first argument.
      options[callback_name].apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
  callback('cb_one', 99, 100);
}
```

What I get in the `a` argument is 'cb_one', but I want that it should be '99'.

```
var a = new SomeThing({
  cb_one: function(a,b,c) {
    console.log(arguments); // => ["cb_one", 99, 100]
    console.log(a);         // => cb_one
    console.log(b);         // => 99
    console.log(c);         // => 100
  }
});
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `options[callback_name].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments,1));`

`[].slice.call(arguments,1)` converts the arguments ('[array-like](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-7/array-like-objects)') `Object` into a real `Array` containing all arguments but the first.

`[].slice.call` may also be written as `Array.prototype.slice.call`.

Comment: It might be clearer to use `Array.prototype.slice.call` instead of `[].slice.call` – that shows that there’s nothing special about the empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what Kooilnc does. Personally however I don't like writing `[].slice.call` or `Arrray.prototype.slice.call`. Instead I do this:

```
var bind = Function.bind;
var call = Function.call;

var bindable = bind.bind(bind);
var callable = bindable(call);

// this is the same as Array.prototype.slice.call
var arrayFrom = callable(Array.prototype.slice);
```

Now you can simple do:

```
options[callback_name].apply(this, arrayFrom(arguments, 1));
```

For more information about `bindable` and `callable` talk to the people in the JavaScript chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Comment: Why `bindable`? Just do `var slice = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);`

Comment: Because in 5 lines of code you get 3 useful functions - `bindable`, `callable` and `arrayFrom` which can be used in many different cases. For example I can use `bindable` on `apply` to create a function `appliable` which takes a function `func` and returns another function equivalent to `func.apply`. In addition it simply looks cleaner.

Comment: @NagaJolokia Oops. I forgot to mention you in the last comment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I see what you're saying, but I still stand by my original comment. I guess the chat room (as you pointed out) would be a better place for further discussion.